# Call back function using `this` in Jquery get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I want to use `this` keyword in the callbacks of $.get(). My code structure is

```
var myObject = {
  get: function() {
    $.get(server,data,function(data,status) {
      this.callback();
    });
  },
  callback: function() {

  }
}
```

I don't want to use `myObject.callback()`. Is there any way to accomplish using `this.callback()`?

Answer (score 5):

You can [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the value of `this` to your callback function before passing it to `$.get()`:

```
var myObject = {
  get: function() {
    $.get(server, data, function(data, status) {
      this.callback();
    }.bind(this));
  }
  callback: function {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Of course, that assumes the value of `this` within your own `myObject.get()` function is correct, which it would be if you called it with "dot notation" as `myObject.get()`.

Note also that if the only thing your anonymous function does is call the other function then you can bind the other function directly:

```
var myObject = {
  get: function() {
    $.get(server, data, this.callback.bind(this));
  }
  callback: function {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: does bind(this) will change the context of jQuery internally? if Not could u please explain?

Comment: Did you read the MDN page that I linked to? `.bind()` returns a new function that is a proxy/wrapper for the function you call it on. It doesn't change how jQuery works, but because you pass that new function to jQuery that is what jQuery calls. The new proxy function then calls your actual function for you, setting the value of `this` to what you specified in the argument to `.bind()`. It's all part of [how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 -- cache `this` in a variable (`_this`):

```
var myObject = {
    get: function() {
        var _this = this;
        $.get(server, data, function(data, status) {
            _this.callback(); // this keyword refers to Window obj not myObject
        });
    }
    callback: function {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Option #2 -- use jQuery's [`.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method:

```
var myObject = {
    get: function() {
        $.get(server, data, $.proxy(function(data, status) {
            _this.callback(); // this keyword refers to Window obj not myObject
        }), this);

    }
    callback: function {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

(Edited-- thanks nnnnnn)

Comment: The `$.proxy()` call would need to wrap only the inner anonymous function, not the `$.get()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn -- yes, but I don't know why I even bother-- you're like ten steps ahead of me :)  Unless there's also like an "nnnnn" and an "nnnnnnn" that make me think you're in more places than you really are...

Comment: Ha, thanks. Your Option 1 covered the technique that I couldn't be bothered to include in my own answer, so I've voted your answer up.